# Adding value to end of linked list and removing from the front c++

Tags: c++, linked-list

I'm attempting to add items to the end of the list and remove them from the beginning of the list. The program compiles but crushes when I try to add items.  I'm new to this concept an it's taking some time to settle in completely. Any help is appreciated.. 
Thanks!

```
  #include<iostream>
using namespace std;



struct myNode
{
    int val;
    struct myNode *next;
};


class Cll
{

public:
    myNode* head = new myNode;
    myNode* tail = new myNode;

    Cll()
    {
        head = NULL;
        tail = NULL;
    }
    myNode* createAnode(int value)
    {
        myNode* temp;
        temp = new myNode;

        temp->val = value;
        temp->next = NULL;
        return temp;
    }
    void addingValues()
    {
        int numb;
        cout<<"Enter the number to be added: ";
        cin>>numb;
        myNode *temp, *p;
        temp = createAnode(numb);

        p = head;
        p = p-> next;
       temp -> next = NULL ;
        p -> next = temp;

    }
        void deletingValues()
    {
        myNode *s;
        s = head;
        head = s->next;
    }

     void showValues()
    {
        struct myNode *temp2;

        temp2 = head;
        while (temp2)
        {
            cout<<temp2->val<<"->";
            temp2 = temp2->next;
        }
        cout<<"NULL"<<endl;
    }

};



int main()
{

    int pick ;
    Cll cll;
    int again;




    do
    {

        cout<<"1.add"<<endl;
        cout<<"2.delete"<<endl;
        cout<<"3.show"<<endl;
        cout<<"Enter choice : ";
        cin>>pick;
        switch(pick)
        {
            case 1:
                cll.addingValues();
                cout<<endl;
                break;

            case 2:
                cll.deletingValues();
                break;
            case 3:
                cll.showValues();
                cout<<endl;
                break;

        }
        cout << "Enter 1 to see again, enter 2 to quit"<< endl;
        cin >> again;

    } while (again == 1);




}
```

Comment: You forgot to tell us what you found out when you debugged the program.

Comment: In `addingValues`: `p = head; p = p->next;` --> `head` is null and you are accessing `next` on a null obj. But there`s a lot more that doesn't look right. Learn how to use a debugger.

Comment: It sounds like you may need to learn how to use a debugger to step through your code. With a good debugger, you can execute your program line by line and see where it is deviating from what you expect. This is an essential tool if you are going to do any programming.  Further reading: **[How to debug small programs](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)**

Comment: Plus your addingValues and deletingValues seem to have many logic flaws. p = p->next won't give you the end of the list but the second element from the list. Is this what you want ? What do you want to happen if your head element is not defined ? How are these functions called ?

Comment: That your constructor sets `head` and `tail` to `NULL` is a problem. Not only because later accessing `p->next` is invalid, but also because you leak the memory you allocated with the in-class member initializers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are programming in c++, so I recommend to use **std::list**.

But if you like to do it yourself, and you like to ad a node at front of your single liked list, you first have to check if it is the first node or not.
If it is the first node your new node ist `head` and `tail`. If not the new node is the the head and its successor is the old head of the list. Adapt your code like this:

```
void addingValues()
{
    int numb;
    cout << "Enter the number to be added: ";
    cin >> numb;
    myNode  *newNode = createAnode(numb);

    if ( head == NULL ) // if list is empty the new node is the head and the tail
    {
        head = tail = newNode;
        return;
    }

    tail->next = newNode; // successor of last node is new node and new node is tail
    tail = newNode;
}
```

To delete a node from front of the list you have to check if the list is not empty and if it was the last node in the list:

```
void deletingValues()
{
    if ( head == NULL )
        return;

    myNode *temp = head->next;
    delete head;
    head = temp;
    if ( head == NULL )
        tail == NULL;
}
```

Comment: She wants to add at the end : " add items to the end of the list"